# gruntfile not color codes like other JS files

Tags: webstorm

For some reason Webstorm will not color the code within a Gruntfile, it opens like a standard text file, I cant seem to find the settings to make it work like a normal JS file. I don't recall changing any setting which could have effected this.

[image]

Comment: Does the Gruntfile use a `.js` extension?  That would be the most trivial reason it wouldn't automatically parse it as javascript...

Comment: yeah it used the extension. Thats whats so weird about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if '`Gruntfile.js`' (or '`gruntfile.js`' if your file name starts with lower case) is added to text file patterns in `Settings | Editor | File types -> 'Text files'` file type. Removing this pattern should solve your problem

Comment: The file is names exactly 'Gruntfile.js' I cant seem to see what you mention under file types

Comment: Update: ok i found Gruntfile.js under the text file type, removed and now working, thanks!